# How to close a game that uses multiple Screen in LIbgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a class that extends `Game`, then a bunch of other classes that implements `Screen` and because of that I can just do this `game.setScreen(new MyScreen(game));` but the problem is that when I do `Gdx.app.exit()` it just closes the current screen and go to the next one, this is the same for `game.dispose()`.So how do you close or exit the game when it's running as desktop or android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing `System.exit(0)`, which should work.

I believe (although I haven't tested this one out), you can also add the line: `config.forceExit(false)` whereas it was previously set to true.